# multiprocessing.Process not working properly

Tags: python, process

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(p,type(p))
```

This program isn't executing properly on my pc...But it works fine using online compiler

```
====================== RESTART: E:\Python\py_prac_9.py ======================
<Process(Process-1, stopped[1])> <class 'multiprocessing.context.Process'>
>>>
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
====================== RESTART: E:\Python\py_prac_9.py ======================
hello bob
<Process(Process-1, stopped[1])> <class 'multiprocessing.context.Process'>
>>>
```

I'm using windows 8.1 with 3.5.4 python version...

```
Environmental Variables:

PATH:
C:\Users\Madhu G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;
C:\Users\Madhu G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\;
C:\Users\Madhu G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;
```

Please suggest me the solution, even the daemon processes are not executing proper...Do I need to make any changes in my pc..

Comment: even the daemon threads are not executing properly...

Comment: Works fine on my PC (Windows 7) with both Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2. How are you executing the script?

Comment: There's a typo here: `args=('bob',))`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working with Python under Windows. If you are starting the script via [IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480498/why-doesnt-print-work-in-python-multiprocessing-pool-map), it won't give you the expected output.

Try starting it via the command line.