# Python multiprocessing not calling function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get this code to work, and it looks like update isn't getting called. Nothing is printed to the console with this code, why?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def update():
    print("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=update, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Stop splitting hairs with the answers you have and run it from the command line. It works and prints "hi"

Comment: **how are you running the code?** It is likely you are using a python environment that overrides `sys.stdout` to catch the output which multiprocessing skips over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your program from the command line, python idle doesn't deal with this correctly as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480498/why-doesnt-print-work-in-python-multiprocessing-pool-map)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid answer, but maybe you do not have time to see the output in stdout? Try running the script from the command line, like this: `c:\<script location>\script.py`

UPD: riscnotcisc said true.

Comment: I'm running in spyder's ipython console, which logs print statements