# Multiprocessing.Pool.Map Does Not Do Anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was trying out multiprocessing because I was trying to imitate an internet and how it's nodes work. I am fine with the basic functionality so I looked on the documentation and used the most basic example on the 3.7.0 documentation, the version I am using now. To my surprise, it didn't work. I am using a Mac OS High Sierra, version 10.13.6, if it has to do with anything. Here is the code for clarity:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I was wondering why it didn't work, as it didn't show anything, and would want the working version, thank you.

[For Those Who Doubt It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ToS.png)

Comment: It worked for me and printed ```[1, 4, 9]``` running your code as is. I don't understand what's the issue here.

Comment: What specifically "didn't work"?

Comment: @nz_21 Look at the picture.

Comment: Most likely duplicate of [Why doesn't `print` work in Python multiprocessing pool.map - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480498/why-doesnt-print-work-in-python-multiprocessing-pool-map) (although I can't tell if that window is IDLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot indicates that you've opened up your interpreter for some reason.

Run your file like so: `python3 main.py`

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://www.learnpython.org/ Also, if the answer works, mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @Aphrodite For some reason `multiprocessing` doesn't like interactive python sessions ('interpreter'). Defining a function during such a session means it cannot be used by `multiprocessing`. Not sure why, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

> pip install multiprocess

`from multiprocess import Pool`

I used `multiprocessing` package like most people, but it didn't work. So I tried `multiprocess` package, and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was using:

```
random.seed = <SOME INT>
```

along with any form of multiprocessing.