# Python script not printing out request status

Tags: python

Im trying to build a python script that is checking all of the links in the file.

It opens a file, reads the sites, and prints them but it doesn't print their statuses and I cant wrap my head around it. It has no syntax errors, all libraries are loaded, function is called.

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

start = time.time()

file = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()

print(urls)

def checkurl(url):
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
        # ...
        print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code) + ', ' + url)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
        # ...
        print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason) + ', ' + url)
    else:
        # 200
        # ...
        print('good' + ', ' + url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=20)
    result = p.map(checkurl, urls)
    

print("done in : ", time.time()-start)
```

The output is

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
===================== RESTART: C:\Users\Anthon\Desktop\b.py ====================
['http://google.com\n', 'http://yahoo.com\n', 'http://thissitedoeesntexistpapgojwpgoajwpogap.com']
done in :  1.954719066619873
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't \`print\` work in Python multiprocessing pool.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480498/why-doesnt-print-work-in-python-multiprocessing-pool-map)

Comment: Could be an issue with your terminal setup like in the above question, especially if you use an IDE. If you run at the command line do you have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing inside checkurl, return a string to the caller. The result variable will contain the data you want to print.