# Function call using multiprocessing not getting executed in python jupyter notebook on Windows

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import os


def bin_for_continuous(i, DV, IV):
    x=[]
    q=str()
    left_bound=pd.qcut(Binning[DV],10).unique()[i].left
    right_bound=pd.qcut(Binning[DV],10).unique()[i].right
    q=str(left_bound)+"-"+str(right_bound)
    x=[x for x in Binning.loc[(Binning[DV] > left_bound)&(Binning[DV]<=right_bound)].iloc[:,0]]
    print(i)
    for j in x:
        df2.loc[df2[IV]==j, IV]=q

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

processes=[]
def main():
    info('main line')
    for i in range(10):
        p1=mp.Process(target=bin_for_continuous,args=[i,"item_cnt_day", "shop_id"])
        p1.start()
        processes.append(p1)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected output is:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 18692
process id: 15836
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This is the only output I get:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 18692
process id: 15836
```

Feels as though the function was never called at all by the code. Running the code without multiprocessing yields the results but using multiprocessing does not yield results. I am trying to learn to trouble shoot from this problem. Hence need your valuable help! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No print output from child multiprocessing.Process unless the program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367053/no-print-output-from-child-multiprocessing-process-unless-the-program-crashes)

Comment: Try running it from a command/terminal/shell prompt:  `py -m filename`. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806280/2823755 - If you want to run it in an interactive interpreter consider using a [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)  to communicate.

Comment: Hi. The code ran on command prompt. Thanks very much for this. Is there a way to run it on jupyter notebook. If not, can you please suggest a better IDE than jupyter notebook? I see many people use different IDEs and seem to get their results from them.

Comment: I don't know all the details but it is because of the way that (most/all?) ide's work - so if you need to have feedback while running child processes via an interactive interpreter (IDE) you can send messages back and forth via a pipe or a queue - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes - or shared state - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes - but you will need to add code to periodically check these things in the main process to get that feedback.

Comment: Sure got you. Thanks.